# Running a UI application on AWS Lambda

Tags: angular, reactjs, amazon-web-services, user-interface, aws-lambda

Is there a way to run a dynamic UI based application on AWS Lambda? If not , why doesn't AWS Lambda fit this use case? Since HTTP traffic is stateless and since session can be maintained in a backing datastore , what restricts lambda from hosting a dynamic web application?

Comment: If it's static, working through APIs, use S3.

Comment: Thanks @AyushGupta. I am looking to run a dynamic app. I have added it to the question now.

Answer (score 2):

Even though lambda is not designed to host UI application, it doesn't mean that its impossible to do so. I had success running `nodejs express` server in lambda where the express endpoints returned html/css.

when it comes to server side sessions, the session could be saved on the database since lambda is stateless.

Answer (score 1):

**No** you cannot run. It is to build/run the APIs of your backend as microservices(serverless architecture). You can either use S3 bucket or Elastic bean stalk to host your UI application.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't host your web interface lambda. You can utilize S3 static website hosting for hosting your HTML and JS code. Lambda can be utilized to provide a backend for any APIs that you need to utilise in your JS code.

Here is a sample architecture and tutorial to learn more about

[image]

Source : [Build a Serverless Web Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)